# Porting web service (SOAP) application to Tandem NonStop

Tags: hp-nonstop, tandem

Can anyone suggest the simplest way to implement a SOAP web service that:

- implements a fairly simple protocol (incidentally, used for secure key management)
- unwraps XML digital signatures
- interacts with the Enscribe file system
- does not have to be as fault-tolerant as a standard Non-Stop process

By "simplest" I mean "has the least dependencies".
Lower cost is not necessarily a worry for now.

I have been advised that XPNET might be the 'platform' to use but possibly there are better ways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are other products besides XPNET that are designed to do this - CSL SOAP for example. I only know a bit about CSL, but I imagine that its competitor products function in broadly the same way.

CSL lets you implement the business end of the logic as Pathway servers which can (of course) access Enscribe resources, and expose that functionality as web services, providing/generating the required code for packaging/unpackaging the SOAP messages.

Probably best to check out the available products and see which one gives you most of the functionality that you require.